# Avoiding self-intersections of immersed manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $i: N\to M$ be an immersion of manifolds. If $\dim M\geq 2\dim N+1$ (or something like that?), does there exist arbitrary small perturbations of $i$ (wrt. some reasonable norm) that are already embeddings?

Comment: This is one of the major steps in proving Whitney's embedding theorem, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know, unfortunately. Any good reference please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is right, see for example John Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", Theorem 6.11.
The main idea is to make (by induction) the given immersion injective on succesively larger sets .

Comment: He has $M=\mathbb{R}^m$ but I believe it works without major changes for a general $M$ as well..